# How to output elements in ElementTree PIParser?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

If you want to preserve comments in an XML file with ElementTree, you can use the PIParser from http://effbot.org/zone/element-pi.htm

So if I have a file containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- This is a comment -->
<root>
  <foo>Hello World</foo>
</root>
<!-- That's all, folks -->
```

then the two comments will be preserved.

PIParser wraps the xml in another `<document>` node, so there is something to contain any comments that come outside the root node. The two comments are just two more elements contained in `<document>`.

But then how should I output the xml? I use code like this to output the contents of `<document>` without outputting the `<document>` tag itself:

```
file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="%s"?>\n' % encoding)
doc = tree.getroot()

for child in doc:
  file.write(ET.tostring(child, encoding, method))
  file.write("\n")
```

Now, that seems to work if encoding is "utf-8". The tostring() method does not output one of those `<?xml...?>` lines, presumably because utf-8 is the default. That's why I wrote the `<?xml...?>` explicitly with file.write() above. But if encoding is "iso-8859-1" then tostring() puts a `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>` at the start of every element for which it is called! So I get one in front of every comment outside the root node, and another in front of the root node itself. I don't want that, I only want one at the top of the file. But instead of getting the xml as shown above, I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<!-- This is a comment -->
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<root>
  <foo>Hello World</foo>
</root>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<!-- That's all, folks -->
```

How do I control whether tostring() outputs a `<?xml...?>`? Or, should I be doing this another way?